# How to tell MongoDB Atlas to stop saving 'Date' type data in UTC format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongodb-atlas

I'm using mongoose as my mapper in the backend. The type is defined in the schema as below

```
 verifyTokenExpiry: {
      type: Date,
 }
```

and then, date is updated,

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(userId, {
        verifyToken: hashedToken,
        verifyTokenExpiry: Date.now() + 3600000,
});
```

although I'm saving in the GMT format, it get saved in the database as

> verifyTokenExpiry
> 2023-11-10T11:30:09.340+00:00

This is a headache when displaying and converting the date and I want a solution to tell the Schema to use a date-format.

I have tried adding the timezone property in schema definition

```
verifyTokenExpiry: {
    type: Date,
    timezone: 'GMT', // Set the timezone to GMT
},
```

and using [moment-timezone](/questions/tagged/moment-timezone)

```
userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  // Convert the date to GMT before saving
  this.verifyTokenExpiry = moment(this.verifyTokenExpiry).tz('GMT').toDate();
  next();
});
```

ultimately changed the timezone of the project settings in Atlas.
none of these was successful!

Comment: Timezone `00:00` is the same as `GMT` (or `UTC` nowadays)

Comment: see https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/tutorial/model-iot-data/#time-representations-in-mongodb

Comment: @dododo this helped me  looks like database decides time format 

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit  GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) and UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) are essentially the same time zone and are often used interchangeably, but they are not tied to a specific offset of 00:00

Comment: `00:00` or `UTC` or `GMT` or `Z` means all the same. Date values in MongoDB are stored as UTC time - **always and only!** If you need to preserve the input time zone, then you must store it in a separate field (as done in linked tutorial). If you store the time zone name or the time-offset is - more or less - a matter of taste. Displaying the date value to the user in correct format and time zone is a different topic. This is the responsibility of your client application, not the MongoDB.

Comment: More importantly, even if you specified another timezone which was not UTC/GMT, [Mongo would convert and store it in UTC](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/tutorial/model-time-data/#model-time-data). So `ISODate( "2021-01-13T06:20:13+02:00" )` would still be stored as `ISODate( "2021-01-13T04:20:13Z" )`. Note the 6:20 --> 4:20 in the saved timed.

Comment: @aneroid gotcha!